# Why is this mysql query only returning null?

Tags: mysql

I am simply trying to query a table to return a boolean value, which seems to only ever return null.

`$sTable4` consists of the columns `userid` & `artistid`

`$artistid` is a parameter passed in to the script (which is definitely being correctly passed)

`$userid` is the id of the currently logged in user.

User are able to save artists in to their `favourites` list.

What I want is to check this table for the currently logged in user and a specific artistid which is declared in the variable above to see if an entry exists. If it doesn't then I want it to return null and to return '1' if it does.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
SELECT userid, artistid
FROM $sTable4 AS b
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT artistid
   FROM $sTable4 AS ab
   WHERE b.userid = $userid
      AND b.artistid = $artistid
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing going wrong, Actually you are trying to select `userid, artistid` from `$sTable4` where they are not exists in the same table, so what do you expect and how would you select them if they are not exists?!! I think you are missing something in  your query, becouse this check will always return null as they are exists, so it won't select them. So i think `where exists` will work for you like this:

```
SELECT ab.artistid
FROM $sTable4 AS ab
WHERE exists 
(
    select artistid 
    from $sTable4 b 
    where b.userid=$userid AND b.artistid=$artistid
)
```

Comment: Oh dear.  It seems all I had to do was remove the 'NOT' and just use the EXISTS functin.  It now works perfectly.  It seems I was simply muddling the two functions up...  How embarrassing!  Thank you anyway MGA. :)